# Error removing a node with firebase cloud functions using .remove()

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

UPDATE - SOLVED: Error in referencing. (Mentioned in Comment). Sorry to take your time.

Whenever a user is assigned to a new manager, I want to remove their reference in the managedby node under the earlier manager. The user node (*) structure looks like this:

[image]

And the managed by(#) (separate node ) looks like this:
[image]

On changing the managed by in the user node:

[image]

Desired output after cloud function is done with:

[image]

My firebase cloud function is this:

```
exports.updatemanagedby = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/managedby').onUpdate(event => {
    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        var earlierHandler = event.data.previous.val();
        console.log("earlierHandler ", earlierHandler)
        var sourceId = event.params.uid;
        console.log("Current UID ", sourceId)
        console.log('/managedby/' + earlierHandler + '/' + sourceId);
        var adaRef = admin.database().ref('/managedby/' + earlierHandler.handler + '/' + sourceId)
         adaRef.remove()
            .then(()=> console.log("removed"))
                .catch((error)=>console.log("error is ",error))
    }  
})
```

On running I receive this on the cloud function log. It even console logs "removed" :[image]

But there is no change in the managedby Node as given in (#). F515DYXZbU.....G2 remains there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Btw I have also used this:  admin.database().ref('/managedby/' + earlierHandler.handler + '/' + sourceId).on('value',function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.ref.remove()
            })

Comment: SORRY. My bad. In the ref.  I have used : earlierHandler.handler rather than using earlierHandler.